# Problems in running class java files in ubuntu

Tags: java, file, class, ubuntu, terminal

I have coded a Java file (Party.java) in ubuntu through gedit - The java code of the file is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Party {
public void buildInvite() {
    Frame f = new Frame();
    Label l = new Label("Party at Tim's");
    Button b = new Button("You Bet");
    Button c = new Button("Shoot Me");
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.add(l);
    } // more code here...
}
```

And then I compiled this code with terminal.
After doing all this stuff when i tried to run Party.class through terminal with the commands:

```
kirat@Virus:~$ cd ~/Desktop
kirat@Virus:~/Desktop$ java Party
```

Its showing me this error  message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

I don't know that whether there is something wrong with my code.
Please help me with this issue

Comment: The error says it all: you need a main method that can be run on startup, otherwise no one knows what to do without no entry point.

Comment: Did you define main() in your class?

Answer (score 0):

you need a main method. File -> Party.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Party {
    public void buildInvite() {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        Label l = new Label("Party at Tim's");
        Button b = new Button("You Bet");
        Button c = new Button("Shoot Me");
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.add(l);
        p.add(b);
        p.add(c);
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Party().buildInvite();  
    }
}
```

Comment: I tries this but its still showing me error that :    kirat@Virus:~/Desktop$ javac Party.java
Party.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method buildInvite()
location: class Party
  new Party().buildInvite();
             ^
1 error

Comment: @user3755172 it was building fine when i tried locally. If you can post entire file code please do so.

Comment: @user3755172 have you changed name of the function 'buildInvite' from the one posted above?

Comment: i am actually following a book : Head First Java 2nd Edition

Comment: @user3755172 I have edited answer. This code compiles fine. Run `javac Party.java` and then `java Party` . As this code does nothing so no output.

Comment: @user3755172 Let me know if you are facing any issues running above edited code

Comment: Yes sir, I am still facing issues while running its saying that: Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
 at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
 at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
 at Party.buildInvite(Party.java:5)
 at Party.main(Party.java:19)

Comment: @Kirat you can contact me via email: sujithvm24@gmail.com and no need to address as 'sir'.